# Ember.js text highlight's pink

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've noticed that ember apps always have a text highlight color or pink. It seems to happen across browsers and OS's for me. Is there any good reason for this or any setting to easily change it?

e.g.

[image: Pink text]

Comment: Assuming you're using ember [starter-kit](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit/blob/master/TODO.txt#L37), what you're seeing is HTML5 boilerplate's default text-highlight color (which, incidentally, was changed to a neutral color as of today's H5BP 4.0.0 release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 boilerplate does this by default... maybe you are using it?

In any case, its trivial to change in css:

```
::-moz-selection {
    background: #anycolour;
}

::selection {
    background: #anycolour;
}
```